# Convert polynomial expression to float coeffs

Tags: maple

This might seem a dumb question but its been a few hours I search about it without really finding exactly what I'm seeking for.

In Maple, if you have a polynomial like this:
[image: maple]

How do I convert this expression to an expression that has floating point coefficients (s^3 + 19s^2 + 89.13s + 71.13) within Maple?

This should just be embedded in the collect() function in my opinion (like a parameter 'float'). Right now I have to calculate myself each polynomial myself (only using Maple to simplify some lengthy calculations in a physics class), which is downright retarded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to evaluate your results using floating point approximation is to use the [evalf](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalf) command:

```
evalf(collect((s+9+Pi)*(s+9+Pi)*(s+1),s));
```

returns

```
147.4182721+s^3+25.28318530*s^2+171.7014573*s
```

If you are really just interested in floating point results, it is worth noting that if one or more of the terms in your original expression is floating point, Maple will evaluate the results in floating point. For example:

```
collect((s+9.+Pi)*(s+9+Pi)*(s+1),s);
```

Also note that I changed your use of lower-case pi (the Greek letter) to Pi (the mathematical constant) in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use (or introduce) any explicitly written float coefficient just to get your desired effect. And indeed you may have good reason to want to have all coefficients be exact, perhaps for some earlier computations.

```
restart;

S := (s+9-Pi) * (s+9+Pi) * (s+1):

sort( evalf( expand(S) ), s, ascending );

                                                    2    3
                 71.13039560 + 89.13039560 s + 19. s  + s

sort( evalf( expand(S) ), s, descending );

                  3        2
                 s  + 19. s  + 89.13039560 s + 71.13039560
```

The above may be useful to you, if this is not adequate:

```
evalf( expand(S) );

                  3        2
                 s  + 19. s  + 89.13039560 s + 71.13039560
```